# Making an object spawn to the left or right relative to another angled object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, trigonometry

Apologies for the long title. What I want to do is to be able to spawn a bullet to the left or right of the centre of an object, the player, which can turn in a full 360 degrees to the left and right. At the moment I am using `x = hypotenuse * cos(player angle)` and `y = hypotenuse * sin(player angle)`. This works very strangely with it working while pointing upwards, with the bullet spawning on the right as intended, but as soon as it is angled downwards it starts spawning on the left.

I have some teacher and we have done some playing around, however they have not been able to help too much as of yet.

Comment: How to you calculate the hypotenuse? Post the part of code where this position assignment is done or your pygame window screen. If I get it correctly, in the first case: the bullet spawns on the right as the player angle is equal to 0.. so `cos(player angle)` = 1 and therefore `hypotenuse * cos(player angle)` i.e. `x` is max. On the other hand.. in the second case.. when the player points downwards, the angle is 90.. as `cos (player angle)` = 0. So.. `x` = 0 and it spawns on the left.. I don't see any problem here or maybe I don't get what you're trying to post. Need more info.

Comment: Please edit your post and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run and test, otherwise it can be very difficult or even impossible to find the cause of the error.

Comment: You'll get an upvote if you show us the code. :) We'll most likely be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I am sorry, it turns out that I was giving the `math.cos`function degrees as opposed to radians. I did try giving it radians earlier, however for some reason it didn't work.